# Flex And Bison, detecting macro statements (newbie)

Tags: c, macros, bison, flex-lexer

I want to teach flex & bison to detect the macro definitions in pure C. Actually i'am adding this function to the existing parser form [here](https://gist.github.com/codebrainz/2933703). The parser itself is good, but it lacks macro functionality. So i did add successfully the `#include` and `pragma` macros detection, but with the selection macroses i have the problems, this is the code in the parser:

```
macro_selection_variants
    : macro_compound_statement
    | include_statement
    | pragma_statement
    | macro_selection_statement
    | statement
    ;
macro_selection_statement
    : MACRO_IFDEF IDENTIFIER macro_selection_variants MACRO_ENDIF
    | MACRO_IFDEF IDENTIFIER  macro_selection_variants MACRO_ELSE macro_selection_variants MACRO_ENDIF
    | MACRO_IFNDEF IDENTIFIER  macro_selection_variants MACRO_ENDIF
    | MACRO_IFNDEF IDENTIFIER  macro_selection_variants MACRO_ELSE macro_selection_variants MACRO_ENDIF
    ;
```

`statement` is declared like so:

```
 statement
    : labeled_statement     
    | compound_statement
    | expression_statement
    | selection_statement
    | iteration_statement
    | jump_statement    
    ;
```

And the lexer part for those macroses is:

```
"#ifdef"        { count(); return(MACRO_IFDEF); }
"#ifndef"       { count(); return(MACRO_IFNDEF); }
"#else"         { count(); return(MACRO_ELSE); }
"#endif"        { count(); return(MACRO_ENDIF); }
```

So the problem is i get the 2 `reduce/reduce` errors because i'm trying to use `statement` in my `macro_selection_statement`. I need to use `statement` in the macro selection block, because those blocks can have variables definitions likes so:

```
#ifdef USER
#include "user.h"
 int some_var;
 char some_text[]="hello";
    #ifdef ONE
        int two=0;
    #endif
#endif
```

What would be the right move here? because i read that `%expect -rr N` is a really bad thing to do with the `reduce` warnings.

Comment: The problem likely comes from how you added `macro_selection_variants` to other rules (`external_declaration` or `block_item` or elsewhere), has nothing to do with `statement` or `macro_selection_statement`.  Use bison's `-v` option to generate a `.output` file detailing the states and where the conflicts are.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really expect to implement a preprocessor (properly) inside of a C grammar. It needs to be a *pre*processor; that is, it reads the program text, and its output is sent to the C grammar.

It is possible to (mostly) avoid doing a second lex pass, since (in theory) the preprocessor can output tokens rather than a stream of characters. That would probably work well with a bison 2.7-or-better "push parser", so you might want to give it a try. But the traditional approach is just a stream of characters, which may well be easier.

It's important to remember that the replacement text of a macro, as well as the arguments to the macro, *have no syntactic constraints*. (Or almost no constraints.) The following is entirely legal:

```
#define OPEN {
#define CLOSE }
#define SAY(whatever) puts(#whatever);

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) OPEN SAY(===>) return 0; CLOSE
```

And that's just a start :)

Comment: Actually i do not need to like, full code of those macroses, my goal is to detect the string literals in the file (string constants, string variables, and define constants) and then encryprt some of them on need. That's my initial target, i know it's kindof a simple task, but it's easier to implement with lex. So if it would just 'eat' those macroses, execpt the string `defines` i would be happy.

Comment: Is it actually possible to make the compiler pre-process the C files, so i can use those with the macro already processed?

Comment: @Vanya: gcc comes with a separate tool (called `cpp`) which preprocesses. Or you can invoke `gcc -E` to just preprocess.

Comment: i looked up the processed file and i think it have more complicated constructions likeso `FILE* __attribute__((__cdecl__)) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__)) fopen (const char*, const char*);` and some other types like `__builtin_va_list`. I think it's a lot more complicated then `defines`. But maybe i try anyway.

Comment: @Vanya: `__attribute__` is a gcc extension. C++ has a specified syntax for attributes, but not C. However, pretty well every production compiler has some way of declaring calling conventions, for example. You can use `#define __attribute__(X)` to get rid of them all (you'll only find them in system headers). `__builtin_va_list` is one of gcc's built-in types intended for use by the standard library. (The standard library requires some features, like va_lists, without specifying a particular implementation. Any symbol starting `__` is reserved.)

Comment: @Vanya: For the syntax of `__attribute__`, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html. (Unfortunately, that description needs to be translated into a formal grammar, so I'd stick with just deleting them by defining `__attribute__` as a macro which expands to nothing.)